# Trying to pass array of strings to destination view controller

Tags: ios, arrays, string, segue

In my app I have parsed images in Collectionview cells that segue when pressed to another screen with the larger image. This works fine.  But,  when I try to add a label that contains an array of strings to the same destination view controller I get :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaaa7520'

Each array,  the image and string have the same amount of indexes.

In First View Controller

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"BottomSegue"]) {
    //DetailShowImageViewController *detailedVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    //detailedVC.detailImageView  =sender;


    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.bottomCollectionview indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPaths);
    BottomCollectionDetail *destinationVC =segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

    destinationVC.imageFromArray  = [bottomArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    destinationVC.string = [arrayOfTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.bottomCollectionview deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


}
```

destinationVC.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewBCD;
@property(weak, nonatomic) NSString *string;
@property(weak, nonatomic)UIImage *imageFromArray;
```

destinationVC.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.imageViewBCD.image = _imageFromArray;
    self.labelOne.text = _string; //This is the line of code that is causing exception
}
```

My issue is trying to get the label to show the string,  that is throwing the exception. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: what is the content of your `arrayOfTitles`?

Comment: are you sure the problem is with your label?

Comment: arrayOfTitles contains parsed strings. The strings are showing in NSLog in original view controller.

Comment: just try this `self.labelOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_string]`

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm calling to seperate indexPaths 1destinationVC.imageFromArray  = [bottomArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 & 2)   destinationVC.string = [arrayOfTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: have you tried the above code?

Comment: Yes, I tried, still same error

Comment: then try commenting the `self.labelOne.text=..` in the `viewDidLoad` and run again

Comment: are you getting this exception before moving to the next view using segue?

Comment: Yes,  on collectionview press.

Comment: put a break point in your `prepareForSegue` method and check whether its being called or not?

Comment: try this one too `destinationVC.string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayOfTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]`

Comment: Your `arrayOfTitles` is a NSString not an NSArray

Comment: NSMutableArray *arrayOfTitles;

Comment: how did you store images in your `bottomArray`, can you show that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaaa7520'` is pretty self explanatory, it's not related to releasing, the problem is that your `arrayOfTiles` is a `NSString` and not a `NSArray`. Check the all the places where you are creating/assigning the `arrayOfTiles`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `arrayOfTitles` it is being `released` at some places. check that part of code. But you can try to set these two `array` with `strong` property.

Comment: Made arrayOfTitles a strong property but still drawing exception.

Comment: have you checked the array at the place you add objects in it, try this: when all objects are added in the array , once checked it with log.

Comment: you can also try to use ViewWillAppear rather than viewDidLoad

Comment: The objects are in place.  The issue seems to be in the prepareForSegue Method